# Struct not stored in memory as expected

Tags: c, memory, struct, esp8266

I'm working with esp8266, Non-OS SDK.

I'm trying to understand how softap_config structure is stored in memory. The reason for this is that I plan to implement configuring espressif over UDP, and I would rather send the whole struct as it should be, and then just memcpy it.

From user_interface.h:

```
struct softap_config {
    uint8 ssid[32];
    uint8 password[64];
    uint8 ssid_len; // Note: Recommend to set it according to your ssid
    uint8 channel;  // Note: support 1 ~ 13
    AUTH_MODE authmode; // Note: Don't support AUTH_WEP in softAP mode.
    uint8 ssid_hidden;  // Note: default 0
    uint8 max_connection;   // Note: default 4, max 4
    uint16 beacon_interval; // Note: support 100 ~ 60000 ms, default 100
};
typedef enum _auth_mode {
    AUTH_OPEN           = 0,
    AUTH_WEP,
    AUTH_WPA_PSK,
    AUTH_WPA2_PSK,
    AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK,
    AUTH_MAX
} AUTH_MODE;
```

So, the first thing I did was:

```
os_printf("size in mem: %d\n", sizeof(struct softap_config));
```

And I got **108** insted of expected **103**.

I then proceeded to printing hex values of:

1. struct fields or their first member if they are an array
2. whole structure as an uint8_t array

What I found is:

1. between channel and authmode there is always [**0x2 0x3**]
2. between authmode and ssid_hidden there is always [**0x0 0x0 0x0**]

It fits perfectly that there are five additional bytes, that explains the size. These bytes stay the same independently of the struct field values, as far as I tested.

But why is it like that? And what could these values mean?
I guess it has something to do with **AUTH_MODE**?

Comment: Alignment.  Make it packed if your platform supports it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "packed"? Is it a method to not align?

And if i can't do that, is it ok just to keep align bytes as they are? I mean, is there any chance that align bytes change?

Comment: if I have to elaborate it - better read something about structs, alignments etc etc

Comment: This is really not a good idea. If, for example, the size of an enum changes in a subsequent compiler version, your network protocol will break.

Comment: good point, will consider it in solving the problem. [:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is two-fold:

1. You don't force the compiler to use short enums, likely with [an option like `-fshort-enums`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html), thus it is free to use a "natural" size, like that of an `int`, in your case 4. Concomittant, the alignment is also 4 instead of 1.
2. `uint16` likely already has an alignment of 2, so even if the enum's size and alignment was 1, the size would be at least 104 unless you use [a compiler-specific extension to pack that struct](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) regardless of alignment-constraints.

Comment: thanks, answers my question [: will accept as soon as i can.